# Vue CLI is not listening to SocketIO events

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vue-cli-3

I'm currently working on a Chat Application using VueCLI and Nodejs.

So I've made proxy connections and everything is working fine including emits from the front-end but VueCLI component is not listening to emit events from the server.

Here is my "sockets" object in the vue component. (In the code below, nothing is appearing in the console for both objects).

```
sockets: {
    connect: () => {
        console.log('socket connected');
    },
    chat: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

and here is my vue-socket.io configuration in "main.js":

```
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket-io'

export const SocketInstance = "http://localhost:9000";
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, SocketInstance);
```

Also, this is my "server.js" code:

```
let io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`One user joined the chat with ID: ${ socket.id }`)

    socket.on("chat", async (chat) => {
        chat.created = new Date();
        let response = await new Message(chat).save();
        io.emit("chat", chat);
    });
})
```

This is my first time using socketIO with a front-end framework and its tiring already, kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in server.js

```
let io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`One user joined the chat with ID: ${ socket.id }`)

    socket.on("chat", async (chat) => {
        chat.created = new Date();
        let response = await new Message(chat).save();
        io.sockets.emit("chat", chat);
    });
})
```